# When is equation has a unique solution?

Tags: calculus

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d7tt.png

> $30$.  For what positive value of $c$ does the equation $\log x = cx^4$ have exactly one real solution for $x$?
>
> $\quad
> \text{(A) } \frac{1}{4e} \qquad
> \text{(B) } \frac{1}{4e^4} \qquad
> \text{(C) } \frac{e^4}{4} \qquad
> \text{(D) } \frac{4}{e^{1/4}} \qquad
> \text{(E) } 4e^{1/4}
> $

I'm stuck in this problem simply because I never encounter this kind before. So do we have a general approach to question like this?

I do not need an answer, I just want to know how to approach this kind of problem.

THank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @LongLêThiên just a heads up, this is the last of these GRE questions I am going to answer for you; I don't even believe I am doing you a service. If you really don't know how to approach the problem at all, you should sit down with a few calculus books before attempting this exam.

Comment: they do, but I don't believe you have no idea how to approach (especially looking at your previous questions). I and others on this site are perfectly happy to offer answers. I was just offering you advice as someone who has taken this exam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is to draw a sketch of the graphs of $\log x$ and $cx^4$. From here it is clear what the question is really asking: We need to have the two graphs intersect, and we also need the intersection to be tangent (otherwise, the two graphs will miss each other, or they will meet twice).

The rest is calculus (really, mostly algebra),
$$
\begin{cases}\log x=cx^4\\
\frac1x=4cx^3
\end{cases}\\
\implies c=\frac{1}{4x^4}\implies \log x=1/4\implies x=e^{1/4}
$$
so $c=\frac{1}{4e}$.